# CSS not applying on Javascript created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I insert fields on my page using the JQuery .html() function. The fields have a class attribute, but it seems like the CSS, which is declared in the header part of the page doesn't apply to the element.

I believe it just impact class selector, since I have a #editZone input selector that work like a charm.

Here's a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    #editZone input, #editZone textarea, #editZone select{
        border:0px;
    }

    #editZone .dependant {
        background-color:#CCC;
        border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    }
    #editZone .original {
        background-color:#FFF;
        border-bottom:1px solid #300;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="headZone">
        Template:
        <select id="template">
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="generateTpl" value="Go" />
    </div>
    <div id="editZone" style="background-color:#ccc;">content will be filled here upon template selection</div>
    <div id="previewZone">final</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a content sample (from firebug):

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc;" id="editZone"><br>
<br>
Name - <input type="" class="original" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name_1"> <input type="" class="original" value="" name="last_name" id="last_name_1"><br>
Title<br>
...
```

Comment: Question is about jQuery, but you don't show your jQuery code?

Comment: works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/yka2w/

Comment: Well considering that the content does populate, I didn't want to polute the question with javascript code that work...

Comment: You should use the tools in your browser to examine the effective style rules of your dynamically-added elements.

Comment: Do you have multiple IDs? Is each thing generated using the id `editZone`? We would know had you shared the JS code...

Comment: Chances are your elements aren't being appended where you think they are. (which we could confirm if you provided js code)

Comment: @Kirean, I see that... obviously I'm missing something ... :-S

Comment: @Kirean, I just tried to put *all* my code in JSFiddle and everything works, must be something with the general document (doc type, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should close the html tags and I think it should work then. Close the tags like `"<tagname />"` or `"<tagname></tagname>"`. I mean input, br and all the opened tags are not closed.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: `<input>`, `<br>`, and many other tags do not have to be closed. Self-closing tags are not meaningful in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that @Pointy, but I think answer is not flagged as HTML5. Am I right?

Comment: It has the HTML5 DOCTYPE at the top :-)

Comment: ... and I do have closing tag, but the part that you see is the firebug dump that remove them...

Comment: Yeah, but maybe the user doesn't now himself that it's the doctype of HTML5. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the style declaration, I had a weird space between the class name and the {.